# no controller ngModel on directive though it works fine

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which has both ngChange & ngModel, which works with input tag. its working as expected but i do get error in console:

```
Error: No controller: ngModel
```

i have two directives, the outerdirective is like below

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace:true,
    template:getTemplate,
    require: ['^form']
}
```

and the inner directive summary is:

```
return {
  scope:{csModel:'@ngModel',csChange:'&ngChange'}, 
  restrict:'E',
  link:linkFunction
}
```

I am not able to understand the reason for the error: here is the plunker [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/BXJ7EN?p=preview) for the same.

Comment: Add this require: 'ngModel' in your outerdirective

Comment: changed outer directive require to: require: ['^form', 'ngModel'] but that still did not solved the problem

Comment: i have provided the plunker link, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with your directive definition..

```
    element.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));
```

replace this line of code with:

```
    element.html(template);
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```